# How to create a file path in bash using head to find the most recent path

Tags: bash, directory, filepath

I need to direct a script to the most recent file in a directory which is in the most recent directory

```
cd /my/path/latestdirectory/more/path/latestfile.trp
```

I can find the latest directory using

```
ls -t | head -n1
```

but I don't know how to assign the output value to the remaining path name

Comment: `variable=$(ls -t | head -n1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You store the value of latestdirectory in a variable.
Then you concatenate the variable with the value of the remaining file path.

Someting like this:

```
latest_dir=$(ls -t /my/path | head -n1)
ls ${latest_dir}/more/path/latestfile.trp
```